# how to convert my CAD files to .xml format so that ROS recognizes it?

Tags: ros, cad

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have modeled an environment using a CAD software. I would like to convert this CAD model into .xml format so that the ROS recognizes it. Suggestions would be helpful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94111/how-to-convert-my-cad-files-to-.xml-format-so-that-ros-recognizes-it-?/) by [vignesh ramani](https://answers.ros.org/users/8086/vignesh-ramani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using SolidWorks, you can try [sw_urdf_exporter](http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter)

---

Originally posted by [Jbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1000/jbot/) with karma: 429 on 2013-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vignesh ramani](https://answers.ros.org/users/8086/vignesh-ramani/) on 2013-11-14**:
Thanks for your reply. But this exporter is not functioning well. When i export my file as an URDF , it shuts the entire solid works. Do you know/ have any other better Solid Works to URDF exporter file?  I am ok with exporting .xml files from other CAD softwares too like AutoCAD , Pro-E , CATIA and Inventor. Thanks in advance